# Lines in a metric space - a metric space?

Tags: reference-request, metric-spaces

In a metric space, a point $x$ is *between* points $u$ and $v$ if $d(u,v)=d(u,x)+d(x,v)$. The *line* determined by points *u* and *v* consists of $u$, $v$ and all points $x$ such that one of $x,u,v$ is between the other two.

How to define a natural metric on the set of all lines in a metric space?

http://www.math.illinois.edu/~dwest/regs/linemetric.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The definition implies that a line is a nonempty closed bounded set. There is a natural metric on the set of such sets: [Hausdorff metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance).

Definition: Given two nonempty closed bounded sets $A,B$, let $d_H(A,B)$ be the infimum of all positive numbers $r$ such that $d(x,B)\le r$ for every point $x\in A$ and $d(x,A)\le r$ for every point $x\in B$.